# Relationship between Type 1 error and Type 2 error

Tags: type-i-and-ii-errors

Given that Type I error is 0.01, what is the highest value possible for Type II error?

Comment: Welcome to across Validated! Without more information, this cannot be answered. Could you please include more information from your homework?

Comment: The value for type I error does not limit the value for type II error. You just need to determine how much power you are aiming for.

Comment: Indeed, without further information, the answer is, in view of the existence of biased tests, 1

Comment: To better understand these concepts it is advisable to drop the word 'error' as these are not probabilities of making errors.  They are strictly the probabilities of making assertions.  Each of the type I and type II probabilities are computed under an unverifiable assumption.  The probability of making an error would be one minus a Bayesian posterior probability of an assertion being true.  But to your question, if you allow the type I assertion probability to increase, the type II assertion probability will decrease if for type II you hold the effect not to miss constant.

Comment: @FEI With a biased test it might be as high as 1; did you leave out any information?

Comment: thank you for your answers! the question is one I received and one I could not answer either, so your answers make sense to me.